# WPF MVVM Command With Key Binding not firing

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Pressing the delete key is not causing the command below to fire.  One can assume DelegateCommand follows interface contracts since other instances of DelegateCommand referenced in the View are properly firing within the ViewModel.

Why?

**View:**

```xml
<ListBox Height="132"
     Name="lbFiles"
     ItemsSource="{Binding LbItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  
     VerticalAlignment="Center"
     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ListBoxSelection}">
<ListBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Delete"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}
                ,Path=DataContext.CommandInputFilesDeleteSelected}" />
</ListBox.InputBindings>
```

**ViewModel:**

```cs
private DelegateCommand commandInputFilesDeleteSelected;

public ICommand CommandInputFilesDeleteSelected {
    get {
            if (commandInputFilesDeleteSelected == null) {
                commandInputFilesDeleteSelected = new DelegateCommand(InputFilesDeleteSelected);
            }
    return saveCommand;
    }
}

private void InputFilesDeleteSelected() { //this never fires :( 
        LbItems.Remove(ListBoxSelection); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private DelegateCommand commandInputFilesDeleteSelected;

public ICommand CommandInputFilesDeleteSelected {
    get {
            if (commandInputFilesDeleteSelected == null) {
                commandInputFilesDeleteSelected = new DelegateCommand(InputFilesDeleteSelected);
            }
    return saveCommand;  //changed from saveCommand to commandInputFilesDeleteSelected whoops
    }
}
```